# Expand function for more arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to know how i can expand function and add more arguments for it like object. For example I have function

```
function xml(){}

xml.prototype.get = function(url, config /*optional*/){
    //something with restApi
}
```

and i want to use mock data for every method and i try to add `mock` and `mockData` like new parameters in object but if i don't pass `config` argument all brokes, but i want to use it outside object.

```
const httpClient = Object.create(xml)
httpClient.get = function(url, config /*optional*/,{mock,mockData}={}){
        if(mock){
          return new Promise(resolve=>resolve({data: mockData}))
        }
        return this.get(url, config)
    }
```

Comment: you can use like this **{mock:undefined,mockData:undefined}** 
or you can pass object variable **function(url, config /*optional*/,MyObject={})**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply have all of the arguments as object property

```
function dummmy({mock,mockData,url,config}={}){
   if(mock){
      return new Promise(resolve=>resolve({data: mockData}))
    }
  return this.get(url, config)
}
```

And then pass whatever values you want to pass

```
dummy({url:'someurl', mock:[1,2,3]})
```

---

```js
function dummy( {a,b} = {} ){
  console.log(a,b)
}

dummy({a:1})
dummy({a:1, b:2})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const httpClient = Object.create(xml)
httpClient.get = function(url, config, mock, mockData) {
    if (!!mock && !mockData) {
        mockData = mock;
        mock = config;
        config = null;
    }
    if(mock){
      return new Promise(resolve=>resolve({data: mockData}))
    }
    return this.get(url, config)
}
```